Why does the pressure sharply increase when the liquid/vapor equilibrium becomes only liquid?
From the US National Chemistry Olympiad:

A sample of a pure substance is placed in a sealed, rigid
container and the pressure is measured as a function of
temperature. Which is the best explanation for the result
shown?



(A) At lower temperatures, the substance is a mixture of
solid and vapor, while at 60 °C the solid melts to
give a mixture of liquid and vapor.

(B) At lower temperatures, the substance is a mixture of
liquid and vapor, while at 60 °C only liquid is
present.

(C) At lower temperatures, the substance is a mixture of
liquid and vapor, while at 60 °C only a supercritical
fluid is present.

(D) At lower temperatures, the substance consists of
vapor only, while at 60 °C only a supercritical fluid
is present.

The correct answer here is B, which I don't exactly understand. I understand that the system being a mixture of vapor and liquid at low temperature makes sense, since as the temperature is raised, the vapor pressure of the liquid increases, and the vapor (which there is now more of) exerts more pressure in accordance with the ideal gas law. I also kind of understand why the mixture would, counterintuitively, become only liquid as the temperature is raised: despite the high temperature, the pressure is too high for gas to exist at 60 C. What I don't understand is why the pressure sharply increases at 60 C. How does the liquid suddenly exert so much pressure? And why couldn't a supercritical fluid explain the behavior at 60 C?

Oh, it's a scenario a bit like https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/what-happens-if-you-cool-water-in-a-container-too-small-for-it-to-freeze See, there was only a tiny amount of vapor in your box and liquid expanded on heating to fill it. Now it's trying to break your box apart.

In the curved part of the graph, is the liquid contributing to the pressure significantly? I assumed that pressure was only due to the gas.

Yes, it was just vapor pressure, but then there's only incompressible liquid.

The heating takes place at constant average specific volume.

When you fully fill a glass bottle with water, close it and start to heat it in water bath, what will happen? The glass will shatter, unless the cork, plug or screw cap shoots away first. If you check water coefficients of thermal dilation(bigger than for glass) and compressibility, you will not wonder.

Ideal gas law applies to the vapor phase and also to supercritical fluids. Now, as the temperature is increased, number of particles per volume unit of vapor increases in addition to kinetic energy per particle. That's why the graph segment is curved rather than a straight line.
At $\pu{60^oC}$ , there is no longer vapor. The liquid has higher number of particles per volume unit. Extra heat provided still increases the average kinetic energy of particles by the same amount with every added temperature unit. Since the liquid cannot expand any more, the pressure goes up more rapidly with temperature. The more the ratio between the density of liquid and gas was, the larger the ratio between the rate of increase of pressure above vs below $\pu{60^oC}$. This effect would diminish if the fluid was near critical.
In fact, the essence of critical points is that approaching it from below causes the densities of liquid and vapor to get more and more similar until they are identical.

So if it became a supercritical fluid, the graph would increase linearly at high temperatures?

@unstable Yes. If you want to learn more, here is a good place to start: https://www.aerogel.org/?p=4

I edited my answer to include the basics about criticality. In case the readers didn't know.

Gases are very compressible, liquids are not
Without getting into too much detail or edge cases (like those that arise with supercritical fluids) the issue is simple. Gases are very compressible, liquids are not.
In this case it seems likely that the situation is one where there is not much vapour to start with. So little that the (small) expansion of the volume of the liquid as temperature increases can eliminate the space occupied by the liquid. Once that point is hit there is no remaining space occupied by the most compressible component, the vapour. So there is no option to absorb extra pressure by shrinking the vapour volume. At this point, there is a sharp kink in the curve as the liquid is vastly less compressible than the vapour.
So the curve to the left of the kink reflects the relationship between pressure and volume of the vapour (and, vapour being very compressible, it is a gentle curve). But to the right, the curve reflects the far, far steeper relationship driven by the very low compressibility of the liquid.
More complex edge-cases to do with phase transitions are not relevant.

By "volume of the vapour " is meant molar volume? or what? Total volume decreases with temperature not only by compression.

Also, note that supercritical fluids are as compressible as gases. Furthermore, liquid completely filling the container does not need to be incompressible as long as its number density is much higher than vapor's at $60^o C$.

@PaulKolk byt volume of vapour, I mean volume. Physical volume occupied by vapor. Volume not occupied by liquid. The key point is that small expansion of the volume of the liquid eliminates any space for vapour and the resulting pressure/temperature curve is purely about the liquid compressibility.

Compressibility is a property of vapor at a constant temperature. You wrote: "the curve to the left of the kink reflects the relationship between pressure and volume of the vapour". This is misleading and incomplete. The equilibrium vapor pressure varies with temperature because of two factors - 1)kinetic energy of particles and 2) number density. Both increase non-negligibly with temperature. The surface of the liquid is not something that simply compresses a gas. It also evaporates. Without understanding this, one cannot distinguish between options B and C.

@PaulKolk Compressibility is a property of all gasses (including vapour). Not just at constant temperature. The simple obvious answer to this question involves the elimination of the vapour by expansion of the liquid. Yes, there are circumstances (but probably at higher temperatures) where supercritical fluids might matter but this question gives no hint that that is relevant. Don't overcomplicate what is intended to be simple question.

There certainly is a hint of increasing vapor density below $60^o C$.  The graph is curved. If this was negligible, the graph would be straight lines. There is no reason to think near-criticality matters only at higher temperatures. The question only specifies that the substance is pure, not that it must have high critical temperature compared to $60^o C$.

I didn't overcomplicate anything, since the OP asked specifically: "And why couldn't a supercritical fluid explain the behavior at 60 C?".
